# Express replaced “%2F” to “/” in URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

In the express middleware

```
 server.get('/abc/test', function(req, res) {
    var token = req.param('access_token')
    return app.render(req, res, "/abc", {
     token: token
    });
  });
```

this will route all **https://domain/abc/test?token=Srasd%2Fmnaismlm%2Bsfas** to **abc** page

Console logging the token value shows **Srasd/mnaismlm+sfas** instead of **Srasd%2Fmnaismlm%2Bsfas**

is there a way to prevent the replacement of these values?

Comment: This is URL encoding problem. You need to decode it . Its simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent` ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent))

```js
const token = `https://domain/abc/test?token=Srasd/mnaismlm+sfas`;
console.log(encodeURIComponent(token));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. The log gives 
`https://domain/abc/test?token=Srasd/mnaismlm+sfas`

Comment: var token = encodeURIComponent(req.param('access_token')) does the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can convert/encode token value to Base64 string while passing in param and decode it again to normal string at /abc/test.

This way your token value's special characters will be encoded and restricted from change.